# Why is my upload speed much higher than my download speed when the signal strength is low?

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a new internet package rated at 300Mbps (we obviously get sightly less). We've not sorted out boosting the signal yet, so there's several rooms with really bad signal strength (as indicated on my phone's WiFi icon).

To no surprise the speed test on openspeedtest.com shows really slow internet speeds when there's low signal.

But to my surprise, the upload speed is mostly constant! No matter where in the house, so long as I have some signal I get good upload speeds!

[image: WiFi speed test results showing 16.07Mpbs download and 45Mbps upload]
And
[image: WiFi speed test results showing 7.64 Mpbs download and 41.23Mbps upload]

Why would they be the case?

Comment: could be that someone is streaming something at the same time? or a big download? or simply that wifi is unpredictable

Comment: @JaromandaX the first two are possible, but this disparity is quite predictable.

Comment: OK, so, have you used a variety of wifi devices to test the speed

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes but I haven't got the results to hand. They're more or less the same.

Comment: Same problem here in a Docker. Ethernet connection - I'm only getting 500 megabit download, but 980 upload. IPERF3 shows full gigabit between same machines. I assume it's a Docker or HTTPS issue.